# How can i merge a /branch to /trunk using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

Assume i have a project in /trunk (revision: 10)
And i have copy all files from /trunk to /branch/2011.06.01 and switch working copy to /branch.

there are some changed made and committed to /branch.

So that there is not sync between /trunk and /branch/2011.06.01,
but how can i merge from /branch to /trunk to make it as same files?

or i just delete all files in trunk and copy from /branch?

Answer (score 2):

I heavily suggest reading [svn manual covering this case in details](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s04.html#svn-ch-4-sect-4.1)

Something like that should do :

```
go to trunk
svn up
svn merge -r 10:latestRevisionHere http://svn.example.com/branch/2011.06.01
```

=> check diffs, pay attention to newly spawned, moved, deleted files
=> commit